# Package a python project with hidden folders

Tags: python

I'm trying to package a project but have been struggling to include a hidden folder in site-packages

I have a list of yaml files in a .templates folder, for example

```
./src/.templates/create-asn.yaml
```

I have a MANIFEST.in

```
include ./resources/config.*
include ./src/.templates/*.yaml
include ./REQUIREMENTS.txt
include ./README.md
```

plus, in setup():

```
setup(
    name='',
    url='',
    version=__version__,
    description=__project__,
    long_description='',
    author=__author__,
    author_email=__author_email__,
    package_dir={'': '.'},
    packages=['resources', 'src/lib', 'src/config', 'src/siewhois', 'test'],
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=install_requires,
    platforms='Posix',
    cmdclass={'test': PyTest},
    scripts=['bin/siewhois']
)
```

How do I go about including these yaml files in .templates in the setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its easier if you put the folders you want to include in `src/<package_name>` so 
`src/<package_name>/.templates`.

Then you can use recursive-include e.g.
`recursive-include src/<package_name>/.templates *`

Comment: as in creating a folder called . ?

Comment: Updated. check again